# Does doing self = self init; return self; in objective-C have the same effect as self.init() in swift?

Tags: objective-c, swift, init

Does doing:

```
self = self.init;
return self;
```

in objective-C have the same effect as:

```
self.init()
```

in swift?

For example, in this context:

```
else if([format.dateFormatType compare: ISO8601DateFormatType] == NSOrderedSame) {
        NSString *isoFormat = ISO8601DateFormatType;
        NSString *dateFormat = (isoFormat != nil) ? isoFormat : ISO8601DateFormatType;
        NSDateFormatter *formatter = [DateFormat CustomDateFormat: dateFormat];
        formatter.locale = [NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier: (@"en_US_POSIX")];
        formatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
        formatter.dateFormat = dateFormat;
        NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:(string)];
        if (date != nil){
            return [self initWithTimeInterval: 0 sinceDate: date];
        }
        else {
            self = self.init;
            return self;
        }
    }
```

Comment: In what context are you wanting to use this?

Comment: Let me edit my question to show you.

Comment: Actually the equivalent is `return [self init];`

Comment: Thank you ! Post it as an answer and I confirm it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent of `self.init()` to call a designated or default initializer in the same scope in Objective-C is

```
if (date != nil) {
   return [self initWithTimeInterval: 0 sinceDate: date];
} else {
   return [self init];
}
```